# Programmatically change the height and width of a UIImageView Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview

Hey for some reason I am struggling with trying to set the height and width of one of my image views. I want to set it so the height only goes for 20% of my screen. I know to regularly set it you can do things like:
image = (0,0,50,50)

But I need the height to not be a static number.
Something like image = (0,0, frame.height * 0.2, 50)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The accepted answer in Swift 3:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: screenSize.height * 0.2)
```

Comment: man thank you the screen thing fixed imageView not abiding .scaleAspectFit rule

Answer (score 21):

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
image.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, screenSize.height * 0.2, 50)
```

Comment: You can do the above code this wayy too `image.frame = CGRect(0,0, screenSize.height * 0.2, 50)` The difference is that this way it looks more swift. CGRectMake is Objective-C style

Answer (score 18):

Using autoview

```
image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(8)).isActive = true
```

Comment: it was a suitable answer for me

Answer (score 5):

Hey i figured it out shortly after. For some reason I was just having a brain fart.

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
```

Answer (score 4):

A faster / alternative way to change the height and/or width of a `UIView` is by setting its width/height through `frame.size`:

```
let neededHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2
yourView.frame.size.height = neededHeight
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use this code

```
var imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(name:"imageName"));
imageView.frame = CGrectMake(x,y imageView.frame.width*0.2,50);
```

or

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame:CGrectMake(x,y, self.view.frame.size.width *0.2, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

imageView is a subview of the main view. It works this way

```
image.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, super.view.frame.width, super.view.frame.height * 0.2)
```